# Llamar al campo de una tabla relacionada de muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel

Necesito jalar el campo de una tabla relacionada de muchos  muchos cuando muestro en una vista.

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas de muchos a muchos una es: `cliente` y la otra es `servicio`. Estos son mis modelos:

**Modelo de la tabla servicio**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Modelo_servicio extends Model
{
protected $table='servicios';
protected $fillable=[
    'descripcion_servicio',
    'consumo_agua',
    'pago_mantenimiento',
    'pago_desague',
];


public function modelocliente(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Modelo_cliente');
}
}
```

**Modelo de la tabla cliente**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Modelo_cliente extends Model
{
protected $table    = 'clientes';

protected $fillable = [
    'nombre',
    'apellido',
    'dni',
    'direccion',
    'asentamientos_id',
    'servicio',
    'condicion',
    'mz',
    'lt',
];

public function Servicio()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Modelo_servicio');
}
public function asentamiento()
{
    return $this->belongsto('\App\Modelo_asentamiento', 'asentamientos_id');
}
}
```

La tabla `pivot` de estas dos tablas es la siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class modelo_cliente_servicio extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'cliete_servicio';
    protected $primarykey='id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'clietes_id',
        'servicios_id',

    ];
}
```

ahora cuando quiero mostrar un dato de la tabla servicio en la **vista**:

```
@foreach($cliente as $client)
            <tr>
                <td>
                      {{ $client->nombre }}
                </td>
                <td>
                      {{ $client->apellido }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                      {{ $client->dni }}
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                      {{ $client->direccion }}
                    </strong>
                </td>
               <td>
                    <strong>
                      {{ $client->asentamiento->nombre }}
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                  {{ $client->Servicio->descripcion_servicio}}//aqui muestro
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td>
```

no me muestra nada y obtengo la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

la tabla pivot de estas dos tablas es la siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class modelo_cliente_servicio extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'cliete_servicio';
    protected $primarykey='id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'clietes_id',
        'servicios_id',

    ];
}
```

Comment: Si es una relación de muchos a muchos, ¿cuál es la tabla intermedia o pivote?

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class modelo_cliente_servicio extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'cliete_servicio';
    protected $primarykey='id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'clietes_id',
        'servicios_id',
        
    ];
}

Comment: ¿ La tabla se llama cliete_servicio o cliente_servicio ?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando no se siguen las convenciones tenés que indicar el nombre de la tabla pivot.
 En tu modelo deberías indicarla de la siguiente manera (en los 2 modelos).

```
public function Servicio()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Modelo_servicio', 'cliete_servicio', 'sevicios_id');
}
```

¿Está bien el nombre de la tabla en el modelo `modelo_cliente_servicio`? 
Quizá la tabla se llama `cliente_servicio` y no `cliete_servicio`

Acá tenés la documentación: [eloquent-relationships#many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

**Respecto al Model Modelo_cliente** en el método `asentamiento()` la relación se llama `belongsTo()` y pusiste `belongsto`.
Probá con esto

```
public function asentamiento()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Modelo_asentamiento::class, 'asentamientos_id');
}
```

Modificando este método al hacer `$client->asentamiento->nombre` debería de funcionar.

Si estás recién empezando el proyecto quizá podrías renombrar las tablas y modelos así se te va a simplificar seguir la documentación.

Podrías hacerlo así por ejemplo:

NombreTabla **servicios** => NombreModelo **Servicio**
NombreTabla **clientes**  => NombreModelo **Cliente**
NombreTabla **cliente_servicio** => NombreModelo **ClienteServicio**

**Campos de "cliente_servicio"**  (Van en singular porque hacen referencia a los nombres de los modelos)
  - servicio_id  (en singular)
  - cliente_id  (en singular)

```
// Modelo Servicio
class Servicio extends Model
{
  public function clientes() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Cliente::class);
  }
}

// Modelo Cliente
class Cliente extends Model
{
  public function servicios() {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Servicio::class);
  }
}
```

Esto debería de funcionar, espero haberte sido de ayuda.
Saludos